# squery not fetching the values in the batch class

Tags: apex, batch, querylocator

need some help for the batch class as i am not able to print the sQuery values in the batch class, not sure what is the correct way to do this one.

kindly some one help me for the correct sQuery in the batch class and how to print the values.
Below is my code :-

```java
global class testbatcg implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    
    private String accountIdString;

    public testBatch(String accountId) {
        accountIdString = accountId;
        System.debug('Here in the Batch class the account ID  == '+accountIdString);
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        string query = 'SELECT Id,Name, AccountId from Contact where AccountId=:accountIdString';
        System.debug('>>>>>>Here is the contact batch list=='+Database.getQueryLocator(query));
        System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>Batch values=='+query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> Scope) {
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not get,,,,can you please explain it agin

Comment: What do you mean by "print the values"?  Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between executing a query (using `database.query()` or `[SELECT ... FROM X WHERE Y]`) and getting a query locator as you're doing.

A query locator doesn't give you the results directly. Instead, it allows you to obtain an *iterator* which can be used to obtain the results.

Depending on the query, it could be possibble to view the results from the `start()` method, but it's much easier (and intended) for you to view the results from within the `execute()` method by using `system.debug()` on the `scope` variable (inside or outside of a loop).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `this.accountIdString` instead of simply `accountIdString` in your constructor:

```
    global testbatch(String accountId) {
        this.accountIdString = accountId;
        System.debug('Here in the Batch class the account ID  == '+accountIdString);
    }
```

Comment: The primary use of `this` here would be to avoid variable shadowing, and shadowing is not an issue in OP's given code. This has no effect on the issue in the question.